# Insert image encoded in base 64 in a word document with python-docx?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, base64, openerp-7, python-docx

I use python-docx to generate word document. the user want that he create a template(in a field description) and when he write for example %(company_logo)s in the template, I replace this expression by the picture of the company that I recupered from the database.
as a first issue, I recupered the logo of a company from the database(Postgresql) and I use this code to replace this expression:

```python
    cr.execute("select name, logo_web from res_company where id=%s",[soc_id])
    r=cr.fetchone()
    if r :
        company_name=r[0]
        logo_company = r[1]


    output = cStringIO.StringIO()
    doc = docx.Document()

    contenu=contenu % {'company_logo': logo_company, 'company_name': company_name,}
    doc.add_paragraph(contenu)
```

The output was a document word that contains the base 64 code of the image as a string. I decoded this code and I tried to add it as a picture with the following code:

```python
logo_company = base64.b64decode(r[1])
doc.add_picture(logo_company)
```

But I have this error that tells to me that argument must be the path to the picture.

```
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation here](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.add_picture) explains that the `add_picture()` method takes a file as an argument. The file can be in the form of a path, or it can be a file-like object, such as an open file or a `StringIO` object. It cannot accept a bytestring containing the bytes of the image, which is what you've tried to do.

So you'll need to convert the image bytes into a file-like object, perhaps using StringIO(), and hand the resulting file-like object to `add_picture()`. That will get it working for you. Something like:

```
logo_file = StringIO(base64.b64decode(r[1]))
doc.add_picture(logo_file)
```

Comment: Hello scanny, it can be added with add_picture() like the following: f_logo_company = open("logo_company.png", "w")
f_logo_company.write(logo_company)
f_logo_company.close()  and after that we use doc.add_picture('logo_company.png',width=Inches(1.0)) but the problem is that i'll can't insert it in a specific position i'll be able only to add it in the document. Remeber that i have a field type text and when the user write %(company_logo)s in this field i should replace it with the logo. And i can't use table because it's just a field.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the current version cannot add an "inline" picture, it can only add one on its own paragraph at the end of the current document. If you want to add an image inline you'll need to develop that functionality, perhaps using the implementation of `add_picture()` as a guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try to develop it